# Ubuntu SDL program

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl

I'm creating a program in C++ with SDL and I need to make a message appear box when I press a key. My code create a window and can capt when I press a key. Here is what already have:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


bool wait_for_events ()
{
  SDL_WM_SetCaption("TESTE DE RATO E TECLAS", "TESTE DE RATO E TECLAS"); //titulo


    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, 0); // criação da janela


    SDL_Surface* temp = SDL_LoadBMP("sdl_logo.bmp"); // leitura do bitamp


    SDL_Surface* bg = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp); // converter


    SDL_FreeSurface(temp);

  SDL_Event event;
  int status;
  char *key;
  bool quit = false;

  printf("Prima 'esc' ou pressione o botao 'x' para sair\n");
  while ( !quit ) {             
    status = SDL_WaitEvent(&event); 

    if ( !status ) {            
    printf("SDL_WaitEvent error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
    }
    switch (event.type) {       
      case SDL_KEYDOWN:         
    key = SDL_GetKeyName(event.key.keysym.sym);
        printf("A Tecla '%s' Foi Pressionada\n", key );
    if ( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )  
      quit = true;
        break;
      case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:           
        printf("Solto\n");
        break;
      case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:           
        printf("Pressionado\n");
        break; 
     case SDL_QUIT:         
      exit ( 1 );
        break;
    }

        SDL_BlitSurface(bg, NULL, screen, NULL); // desenho do fundo


        SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }


    SDL_FreeSurface(bg);


    SDL_Quit();
  return true;
}

int main()
{   

  SDL_Surface *screen;

  //iniciação do sistema de video
  if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro na inicializacao do SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
  }
  atexit(SDL_Quit);

  //tamanho da janela, resolução bits
  screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 16, SDL_SWSURFACE);
  if ( screen == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro na resolucao 640x480 video: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
  }

  wait_for_events();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple way for messagebox:

```
char buf[1024];
sprintf(buf, "xmessage -center \"%s\"", mymessage);
system(buf);
```

it might be better to go with gtk/qt instead for proper GUI integration.

Comment: How can i associate with a key?